# Android selector with textColor

Tags: android, xml, android-tv, android-selector

I have created a selector:

btn_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />

    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_focused" android:state_focused="true" />

    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_default" />
</selector>
```

btn_bg_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/btn_pressed"/>
</shape>
```

btn_bg_focused.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/reality_fix_yellow"/>
</shape>
```

btn_bg_default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/btn_default_border_color" />
</shape>
```

I want to change the `text color` the button when the focus changes. I've tried adding `android:color="color_code"` and `android:textColor="color_code"` but failed.
Please help me on **How to change the text color of a button with selector?**

Comment: add <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawableName" android:state_pressed="true" />

Comment: @Anas Azeem did you see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Define this way :

Create **button_selector.xml** file in `res/color` directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

and in `Button` property define this way.

```
<Button
    android:TextColor="@color/button_selector"
/>
```

Comment: the correct is `<Button  android:TextColor="@drawable/button_selector"/>` like You Qi said

Answer (score 2):

There's a trick where you can reuse your background drawable resource to change color for your text.

In your `layout.xml`, declare your button `background` and `textColor` in the following way:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
    android:textColor="@drawable/btn_bg"
    android:text="Hello"  />
```

Now, in your `drawable/btn_bg.xml`, define `android:color="@color/your_color_code"` as the `item` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:color="@color/md_green_500" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />

    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="@color/md_red_500" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_focused" android:state_focused="true" />

    <!-- default -->
    <item android:color="@color/md_blue_500" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg_default" />
</selector>
```

You should be able to see background and text color change for your button.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this on your own TextView class that extends the Android [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) class and override the [`onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

You can then modify the instances text color based on the MotionEvent passed.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
       // Change color
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
       // Change it back
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```